# What am I missing setting up a mean stack with public instead of server side views (express)

Tags: mean-stack

This may come off as opinion, but I really do not know.  What is the difference between setting up the views in the public directory as opposed to the being placed on the server?  I know express sets up with JADE in the server, but I see equal amounts of tutorials with html files that are public.  I do not understand what my benefits or concerns are.  Could someone please explain?

Comment: Do you have a simple example to demonstrate ```What is the difference between setting up the views in the public directory as opposed to the being placed on the server?``` ?

Answer (score 0):

In a default express app the public folder is configured to serve static resources that require no server-side processing.  Any assets (images, scripts, html) in this folder will be url addressable directly from the client.

There is no benefit in placing your jade files in this folder as making them accessible to the client is meaningless and could present a potential security concern.  You could configure express to read the jade files from the public folder server-side but I can't think of any valid reason to do this.